# Set timeout to be stopped with any condition

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I' m making a soft and adding a help speech button. OnClick takes to the change of image(soundon)and starts sound. Now i added a set timeout so that the image changes(soundoff) when the audio ends but i have a problem if i start it and stop it the time out do not stops  and when I press it again the image changes before the time

The main problem is that if i press the button to start sound and again press it to stop it (stopped after 5 sec before the sound ended) If I again click to start, the image changes 5 sec before the audio stops.

I need Javascript code, not jQuery.

---

*2 images | soundon.png and soundoff.png*                                                            AND
*1 audio  | helpsound.mp3*

---

---

HERE IS THE CODE:

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
var clickNumber = 2;
function sound(soundfile) {

image = document.getElementById('snd')
switch (clickNumber) {
    case 1:                                                     
    document.getElementById('snd').src = "images/soundoff.png";
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= "";

    clickNumber = 2;
    return(false);

    case 2:
    document.getElementById('snd').src = "images/sound.png";
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\"/>";

    setTimeout
        (
        function()
            {
        document.getElementById('snd').src = "images/soundoff.png";
            },10000                     
        );
    clickNumber = 1;
    break;
     }
}
```

***HTML***

```
<img src="images/soundoff.png" title="Turn On/Off Help Speech" onclick="sound('helpsound.mp3');" name="soundimg" id="snd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clearTimeout` to cancel the timer:

```
var clickNumber = 2,
    timeoutId = null;

function sound(soundfile) {
    image = document.getElementById('snd');
    switch (clickNumber) {
        case 1:                                                     
        image.src = "images/soundoff.png";
        document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= "";

        if(timeoutId !== null) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = null;
        }

        clickNumber = 2;
        return(false);

        case 2:
        image.src = "images/sound.png";
        document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML='<embed src="' + soundfile + '" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" />';

        timeoutId = setTimeout(
            function() {
                image.src = "images/soundoff.png";
            },10000
        );
        clickNumber = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I Need to click the button 2 times to again start it